# How to print array of objects created in another class

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to ask you for help.I want to print array of objects created by constructor in class FIELD.I want to print it in class ConsoleUI in update() method.

Here is the constructor

```
public Field(int rowCount, int columnCount, int mineCount) {
    this.rowCount = rowCount;
    this.columnCount = columnCount;
    this.mineCount = mineCount;
    tiles = new Tile[rowCount][columnCount];
    generate();
}
```

Here is the update method. It could be wrong. I think I need to overtype Field to Tile somehow.

```
public void update() {  
    int row, column;
    System.out.println("   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");   
    for (row=0; row < field.getRowCount(); row++) {
        switch(row){  
           case 0:System.out.print("A ");break;
           case 1:System.out.print("B ");break;
           case 2:System.out.print("C ");break;
           case 3:System.out.print("D ");break;
           case 4:System.out.print("E ");break;
           case 5:System.out.print("F ");break;
           case 6:System.out.print("G ");break;
           case 7:System.out.print("H ");break;
           case 8:System.out.print("I ");break;
        }
        for (column=0; column < field.getColumnCount() ; column++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
          int r;
          int c;
            Tile t = (Tile) field[r][c];
            for (Field field : t.getState());
            System.out.print(field[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not following your question..

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I need to print array created by constructor to the terminal without UI.it's playing field for minesweeper

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, create a get method in your Field class.

```
public Tile getTile(int row, int col)
{
    return tiles[row][col];
}
```

Then in your class with the update method, create a Field object

```
Field field = new Field();
```

and call

```
field.getTile(row,col);
```

whenever you need a tile.

That is if I understood what you are asking.